# When doing implicit resolution with type parameters, why does val placement matter?

Tags: scala, implicit

In one file, I have:

```scala
trait JsonSchema[T] {
  val propertyType: String

  override def toString: String = propertyType
}

object JsonSchema {
  implicit def stringSchema: JsonSchema[String] = new JsonSchema[String] {
    override val propertyType: String = "string"
  }

  implicit def intSchema: JsonSchema[Int] = new JsonSchema[Int] {
    override val propertyType: String = "integer"
  }

  implicit def booleanSchema: JsonSchema[Boolean] = new JsonSchema[Boolean] {
    override val propertyType: String = "boolean"
  }
}
```

In my main file:

```scala
case class MetaHolder[T](v: T)(implicit val meta: JsonSchema[T])

object JsonSchemaExample extends App {
  println(MetaHolder(3).meta.toString)
  println(MetaHolder("wow").meta.toString)
}
```

That works hunky-dory. Now suppose I do this instead:

```scala
case class MetaHolder[T](v: T) {
  val meta: JsonSchema[T] = implicitly[JsonSchema[T]]
}
```

It no longer compiles. Why?

My goal is to modify the anonymous `Endpoint` classes in the scala Finch library by adding a `val meta` to everything. I've been able to do this without any fancy-business so far, but now I want to do some fancy implicit resolution with shapeless to provide a `JsonSchema` definition for arbitrary case classes. My question is how to do this while maintaining backward compatibility. As in: provide the jsonschema meta feature for people who want to opt in, don't change the compilation burden for anyone who does not want to use meta,

If instead I go the first route, with an added implicit parameter, wouldn't that require a special import to be added by everyone? Or am I missing something and would backward compatibility still be maintained?

Comment: It is recommended to first understand how implicits work. See [**where does Scala looks for implicits**](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html) it should be clear why you redactor didn't make sense. Also, I do not understand what do you mean with users requiring an special import. - Finally, your implicits definitions at the beginning should have been `vals` instead of `defs`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is big difference between `implicit x: X` among parameters and `implicitly[X]` inside body.

When you say `implicitly[X]` this means "check now whether in the current scope there is an implicit `X`".

When you say `def foo(...)(implicit x: X) = ...` this means "check later when `foo` is called that in the scope of the call site there will be an implicit `X` (and for now inside `foo` just assume without checking that there is)".

`class Foo(...)(implicit x: X)` is similar to the latter, "check when constructor is called that there will be an implicit `X`".

Regarding whether users have to import or not. If you put implicits for type `X` to companion object of `X` then they will be found automatically (implicits for type `X[Y]` should be put to companion object of either `X` or `Y`). If you put them somewhere else then they have to be imported to the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

In order for `implicitly[JsonSchema[T]]` to compile, there must be a `JsonSchema[T]` in the implicit scope, which means that there must be a `JsonSchema[T]` (or something implicitly convertible to a `JsonSchema[T]`) passed through as an implicit argument, as you had with:

```
case class MetaHolder[T](v: T)(implicit val meta: JsonSchema[T])
```