# Setting abstract type based on typeclass

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit

I have an example like this:

```
abstract class IsBaseTC[A] { type Self }
abstract class JustHoldsTypeMember[A] extends IsBaseTC[A] 
implicit val doubleHoldsTypeMember = new JustHoldsTypeMember[Double] { type Self = Double }

abstract class IsActualTC[A, T](implicit val aIsBaseTc: IsBaseTC[T]) extends IsBaseTC {
  type Self = A
  def get(self: A): aIsBaseTc.Self
}

case class Container[T](
  get: T
)

implicit val containerOfDoubleIsActual = new IsActualTC[Container[Double], Double] {
  def get(self: Self) = self.get // type mismatch; 
                                  // found self.get.type (with underlying type Double) 
                                  // required this.aIsBaseTc.self
}
```

Which gives me the error shown above. Unless I have failed to follow my own logic through correctly, `this.aIsBaseTc.self` should resolve to a `Double`. Is there a way to persuade the compiler that this is the case?

Grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is in scopes.

Simpler example is

```
trait A { type T }
implicit val a: A { type T = Int } = null
def test(implicit x: A): Unit = {
  implicitly[x.T =:= Int] // doesn't compile, cannot prove that x.T =:= Int
}
```

You assume that `x` is `a` (`aIsBaseTc` is `doubleHoldsTypeMember` in your notations). But actually `x` is not `a`, `x` will be resolved when `test` is called (in the scope of `test` call site) but `a` is defined in current scope (scope of `test` definition). Similarly, `aIsBaseTc` is not `doubleHoldsTypeMember`.

[When doing implicit resolution with type parameters, why does val placement matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59391232/when-doing-implicit-resolution-with-type-parameters-why-does-val-placement-matt) (See the difference between `implicit x: X` and `implicitly[X]`.)

As for any anonymous class

```
implicit val containerOfDoubleIsActual = new IsActualTC[Container[Double], Double] {
  def get(self: Self) = self.get // type mismatch; 
}
```

is a shorthand for

```
class IsActualTCImpl extends IsActualTC[Container[Double], Double] {
  def get(self: Self) = self.get // type mismatch; 
                                 // aIsBaseTc is not doubleHoldsTypeMember here
}
implicit val containerOfDoubleIsActual = 
  new IsActualTCImpl // implicit is resolved here
                     // aIsBaseTc becomes doubleHoldsTypeMember here
```

And since `aIsBaseTc` is not `doubleHoldsTypeMember`, `aIsBaseTc.Self` is not `Double`.

Possible fix is to add one more type parameter `S` to `IsActualTC`

```
abstract class IsActualTC[A, T, S](implicit val aIsBaseTc: IsBaseTC[T] {type Self = S}) extends IsBaseTC {
  type Self = A
  def get(self: A): S
}

implicit val containerOfDoubleIsActual = new IsActualTC[Container[Double], Double, Double] {
  def get(self: Self) = self.get
}
```

or to add a type refinement to the implicit parameter of `IsActualTC`

```
abstract class IsActualTC[A, T](implicit val aIsBaseTc: IsBaseTC[T] {type Self = T}) extends IsBaseTC {
  type Self = A
  def get(self: A): aIsBaseTc.Self
}

implicit val containerOfDoubleIsActual = new IsActualTC[Container[Double], Double] {
  def get(self: Self) = self.get
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is true that both are doubles, but that is the value. It is not the same type.

The type that is requested by `def get(self: A)` is `aIsBaseTc.Self`, which is in your case `doubleHoldsTypeMember.Self`

when trying to access self of `doubleHoldsTypeMember` you get:

[image]

The issue is, that you cannot create `this.aIsBaseTc.Self` because it is not accessible.

In order to resolve it, you can try to create an instance of `Self` where you can access it:

```
abstract class IsBaseTC[A] { type Self; def createSelf(): Self }
abstract class JustHoldsTypeMember[A] extends IsBaseTC[A]
implicit val doubleHoldsTypeMember: JustHoldsTypeMember[Double] = new JustHoldsTypeMember[Double] {
  type Self = Double
  override def createSelf() = 3.14
}
```

and use it:

```
implicit val containerOfDoubleIsActual: IsActualTC[Container[Double], Double] = new IsActualTC[Container[Double], Double] {
  override def get(self: Self) = this.aIsBaseTc.createSelf()
  override def createSelf() = ???
}
```

Then, when running:

```
containerOfDoubleIsActual.get(Container(4.12))
```

it will print:

```
3.14
```

which was created at createSelf of `doubleHoldsTypeMember`

Comment: *"The type that is requested by `def get(self: A)` is `aIsBaseTc.Self`, which is in your case `doubleHoldsTypeMember.Self`"* I don't think this is literally true. *"you cannot create `this.aIsBaseTc.Self` because it is not accessible"* It's not clear what "being accessible" means. Accessible in what sense? Accessible where? Not accessible why?

Comment: In `override def get(self: Self) = this.aIsBaseTc.createSelf()` you "create self" instead of use existing parameter `self` (which you just ignore).