# Typeclass ops : Enable to find implicit value for parameter

Tags: scala, typeclass, implicit, shapeless

i'm new to typeclass pattern and implicit in scala, below is a code snippet i did to test this pattern, but i don't know why the compareB method is not able to find implicit value for the parameter **wrapper** , even so i have an implicit field of type IntWrapper[Int] declared.

Does anyone have an idea how implicit are resolved in typeclass ? and why the code below does not compile ?

Thanks

```
trait IntWrapper[T]{
  def test: Boolean
}

trait ProductComparator[T] extends Serializable{
  def compare(p1 : T, p2: T): Boolean
}

object ProductComparator{

  def apply[A](implicit cmp: ProductComparator[A]) : ProductComparator[A] = cmp


  implicit def w: IntWrapper[Int] =
    new IntWrapper[Int] {
      override def test: Boolean = true
    }

  implicit def CompareB[T <: Product, Repr <: HList, KRepr <: HList](implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, Repr], keys: Keys.Aux[Repr, KRepr], wrapper:  IntWrapper[Int]) : ProductComparator[T] =
      new ProductComparator[T] {
        override def compare(p1: T, p2: T): Boolean = {
          p1.productArity == p2.productArity
        }
      }

}


case class Emp(a: Int, b: Int)

object Demo extends App{
  val comparator = implicitly[ProductComparator[Emp]]
}
```

Comment: In `CompareB` you don't actually use any of implicits `gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, Repr], keys: Keys.Aux[Repr, KRepr], wrapper:  IntWrapper[Int]`. So I guess it's just for example. Right?

Answer (score 4):

Normally implicits for type `TC[A]` are put either to the companion object of `TC` or companion object of `A`.

So transfer

```
implicit def w: IntWrapper[Int] =
  new IntWrapper[Int] {
    override def test: Boolean = true
  }
```

from the companion object of `ProductComparator` to the companion object of `IntWrapper`

```
object IntWrapper {
  implicit def w: IntWrapper[Int] =
    new IntWrapper[Int] {
      override def test: Boolean = true
    }
}
```

Then the code should compile.

Alternatively you can import `w` as **@TomerShetah** proposed.

[Where does Scala look for implicits?](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/FAQ/finding-implicits.html)

When you define

```
implicit val foo: Foo = ???

def bar(implicit foo1: Foo) = ???
```

(in your example `foo` is `w`, `bar` is `CompareB`, `Foo` is `IntWrapper[Int]`)
you shouldn't generally assume that `foo1` is `foo`. `foo` is defined in the current scope and `foo1` will be resolved in the scope of `bar` call site. This can be `foo` if it's there in a scope or some other implicit.

[When doing implicit resolution with type parameters, why does val placement matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59391232/when-doing-implicit-resolution-with-type-parameters-why-does-val-placement-matt)

[Setting abstract type based on typeclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64238219/setting-abstract-type-based-on-typeclass)

[Reverse HList and convert to class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64432145/reverse-hlist-and-convert-to-class)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is scopes. In the line:

```
val comparator = implicitly[ProductComparator[Emp]]
```

The method:

```
def apply[A](implicit cmp: ProductComparator[A]): ProductComparator[A] = cmp
```

Will be called, where `A` is `Emp`. The implicit that can create that, is `CompareB`. `CompareB` Needs more implicits. The first 2, comes from imports. So they are in scope. The variable `w` is defined on the `object ProductComparator` therefore it is not in the scope where you define `val comparator`.

In order to add it to scope, you have few options:

1. Importing it with:

   ```
   import ProductComparator.w
   ```
2. Moving `implicit def w: IntWrapper[Int]` to the same scope as `trait IntWrapper[T]`, which makes:

```
import shapeless.ops.record.Keys
import shapeless.{HList, LabelledGeneric}

trait IntWrapper[T]{
  def test: Boolean
}

implicit def w: IntWrapper[Int] =
  new IntWrapper[Int] {
    override def test: Boolean = true
  }

trait ProductComparator[T] extends Serializable{
  def compare(p1 : T, p2: T): Boolean
}

object ProductComparator{

  def apply[A](implicit cmp: ProductComparator[A]) : ProductComparator[A] = cmp

        implicit def CompareB[T <: Product, Repr <: HList, KRepr <: HList](implicit gen: LabelledGeneric.Aux[T, Repr], keys: Keys.Aux[Repr, KRepr], wrapper:  IntWrapper[Int]) : ProductComparator[T] =
          new ProductComparator[T] {
            override def compare(p1: T, p2: T): Boolean = {
              p1.productArity == p2.productArity
            }
          }

}

case class Emp(a: Int, b: Int)

object Demo extends App{
  val comparator = implicitly[ProductComparator[Emp]]
}
```

To read more about where does Scala look for implicits you can read [Daniels brilliant post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5598107/2359227).

Comment: I dont want to create ProductComparator[Emp] manually, actualy the implicit def CompareB would create it for me, my question is , why the compareB is not able to find wrapper:  IntWrapper[Int] parameter in her scope ? please note that when i remove this parameter the code compiles

Comment: The param to remove is {wrapper:  IntWrapper[Int]}

Comment: Right. So you do even need it? The issue here is scoping. You need to `import ProductComparator.w` in your main application, and then it will find it.

Comment: @TomerShetah *"The first 2, comes from imports. So they are in scope."* Actually, **implicits** `LabelledGeneric` and `Keys` do not come from imports. The imports of `LabelledGeneric` and `Keys` bring their names to the local scope, not the implicits themselves. The implicits for `LabelledGeneric` and `Keys` are in **implicit scope** because they are defined in the companion objects of `LabelledGeneric` and `Keys`.