# In scala, is it possible to initialise a singleton object from a TypeTag?

Tags: scala, dependent-type, path-dependent-type, singleton-type, scala-2.13

Assuming that I have a class with a TypeTag:

```
case class TypeViz[T : TypeTag]() {

  def getOnlyInstance = ...
}
```

Is it possible to use the TypeTag in runtime to find the value of `T`, if `T` is a singleton type? Namely:

```scala
object TypeViewsSpec {

  val a = 3

  val b = new Object {

    val c = 3
  }
}


    it("object") {

      val v = TypeViz[TypeViewsSpec.type]
      assert(v.getOnlyInstance == TypeViewsSpec)
    }

    it("constant") {

      val v = TypeViz[3].typeView
      assert(v.getOnlyInstance == 3)
    }

    it("unique value") {

      val v = TypeViz[TypeViewsSpec.a.type].typeView
      assert(v.getOnlyInstance == 3)
    }

    it(" ... more complex") {

      val v = TypeViz[TypeViewsSpec.b.c.type].typeView
      assert(v.getOnlyInstance == 3)
    }
```

I'm not sure if this feature is provided natively in scala reflection. So please suggest any library/hack whenever possible without changing the signature of the class `TypeViz`

Thanks a lot for your opinion.

Comment: What is `.typeView`?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you know about `scala.ValueOf` and `shapeless.Witness`

```
case class TypeViz[T : TypeTag]() {
  def getOnlyInstance(implicit valueOf: ValueOf[T]) = valueOf.value
}
```

```
case class TypeViz[T : TypeTag]() {
  def getOnlyInstance(implicit witness: Witness.Aux[T]) = witness.value
}
```

If you want to avoid implicit parameters like in [In scala 2, can macro or any language feature be used to rewrite the abstract type reification mechanism in all subclasses? How about scala 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67258252/in-scala-2-can-macro-or-any-language-feature-be-used-to-rewrite-the-abstract-ty), again it's not clear what the goal is.