# Implicit Json Formatter for value classes in Scala

Tags: json, scala, formatting, implicit, play-json

I have many value classes that make up a larger object case class.

```
final case class TopLevel(
  foo: Foo,
  bar: Bar
)

final case class Foo(foo: String) extends AnyVal

final case class Bar(bar: String) extends AnyVal

object Foo {
  implicit val format = Json.valueFormat[Foo]
}

object Bar {
  implicit val format = Json.valueFormat[Bar]
}

object TopLevel {
  implicit val TopLevelFormat: OFormat[TopLevel] = Json.format[TopLevel]
}
```

This works fine, but when the top level case class has many arguments the construction objects soon pile up. I tried to do this implicitly, e.g.

```
object Format {
  implicit def jsonFormatter[A](): Format[A] = Json.valueFormat[A]
}
```

But I get

```
scala.ScalaReflectionException: <none> is not a method
```

Answer (score 1):

`format` and `valueFormat` are macros (well, actually not themselves but they call macros). So you can't call them where you want. `Json.valueFormat[A]` is trying to expand where `A` is not a value class yet but an abstract type (a type parameter). If you'd like to postpone expansion of the macros you can make your implicits [implicit macros](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/implicits.html)

```scala
// in a different subproject
import play.api.libs.json.{Format, OFormat}
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.whitebox

object Format {
  implicit def valueFormat[A]: Format[A] = macro MacroImpl.valueFormatImpl[A]
  implicit def format[A]: OFormat[A] = macro MacroImpl.formatImpl[A]
}

class MacroImpl(val c: whitebox.Context) {
  import c.universe._
  val json = q"_root_.play.api.libs.json.Json"
  def valueFormatImpl[A: WeakTypeTag]: Tree = q"$json.valueFormat[${weakTypeOf[A]}]"
  def formatImpl[A: WeakTypeTag]: Tree = q"$json.format[${weakTypeOf[A]}]"
}
```

Now you don't need to define implicits in companion objects of your classes or value classes. You just need to import implicits  from `Format` to where you need them

```
final case class TopLevel(foo: Foo, bar: Bar)
final case class Foo(foo: String) extends AnyVal
final case class Bar(bar: String) extends AnyVal

import Format._
implicitly[Format[Foo]].writes(Foo("a")) // {"foo":"a"}
implicitly[Format[Bar]].writes(Bar("b")) // {"bar":"b"}
implicitly[Format[TopLevel]].writes(TopLevel(Foo("a"), Bar("b"))) // {"foo":{"foo":"a"},"bar":{"bar":"b"}}
implicitly[OFormat[Foo]].writes(Foo("a")) // {"foo":"a"}
implicitly[OFormat[Bar]].writes(Bar("b")) // {"bar":"b"}
implicitly[OFormat[TopLevel]].writes(TopLevel(Foo("a"), Bar("b"))) // {"foo":{"foo":"a"},"bar":{"bar":"b"}}
```

Alternatively, you can define [macro annotation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) for classes or companion objects. It will generate necessary implicits inside companion objects. But I guess now implicit macros are a little easier than macro annotation.