# In Scala 2.13, why is it possible to summon unqualified TypeTag for abstract type?

Tags: scala, implicit, type-erasure, scala-reflect, scala-2.13

Considering the following code:

```
import scala.reflect.api.Universe

object UnqualifiedTypeTag {

  val RuntimeUniverse = scala.reflect.runtime.universe

  trait HasUniverse {

    val universe: Universe with Singleton

    def uType: RuntimeUniverse.TypeTag[universe.type] = implicitly
  }

  object HasRuntime extends HasUniverse {

    override val universe: RuntimeUniverse.type = RuntimeUniverse
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(HasRuntime.uType)
  }
}
```

Ideally, this part of the program should yield `TypeTag[HasRuntime.universe.type]`, or at least fail its compilation, due to `implicitly` only able to see `universe.type`, which is not known at call site. (in contrast, `WeakTypeTag[universe.type]` should totally work)

Surprisingly, the above program yields `TypeTag[HasUniverse.this.universe.type]`. This apparently breaks many contracts, namely:

- TypeTag cannot be initialised from abstract types, unlike WeakTypeTag
- TypeTag can always be erased to a Class

What's the purpose of this design, and what contract does TypeTag provide? In addition, is this the reason why ClassTag was supposed to be superseded after Scala 2.11, but instead was kept as-is until now?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to still confuse `implicitly[X]` and `(implicit x: X)`

[When doing implicit resolution with type parameters, why does val placement matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59391232/when-doing-implicit-resolution-with-type-parameters-why-does-val-placement-matt)

[In scala 2, can macro or any language feature be used to rewrite the abstract type reification mechanism in all subclasses? How about scala 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67258252/in-scala-2-can-macro-or-any-language-feature-be-used-to-rewrite-the-abstract-ty)

[SYB `cast` function in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74148670/syb-cast-function-in-scala)

[Setting abstract type based on typeclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64238219/setting-abstract-type-based-on-typeclass)

There is no implicit resolution in the line `println(HasRuntime.uType)`. Implicits are resolved in the right hand side of the line `def uType: RuntimeUniverse.TypeTag[universe.type] = implicitly`. For implicits, the call site is not `HasRuntime.uType`, the call site is `implicitly`.

Simpler example is the following (let's make the code self-contained and remove macros or compiler `TypeTag` magic, keeping ordinary implicits)

```
trait MyTypeclass[A] {
  def apply(): String
}
object MyTypeclass {
  implicit def universe[U <: Universe]: MyTypeclass[U] = () => "Universe"
  implicit val runtimeUniverse: MyTypeclass[RuntimeUniverse.type] = () => "RuntimeUniverse"
}

trait Universe
object RuntimeUniverse extends Universe

trait HasUniverse {
  val universe: Universe with Singleton
  def uType: MyTypeclass[universe.type] = implicitly
}

object HasRuntime extends HasUniverse {
  override val universe: RuntimeUniverse.type = RuntimeUniverse
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  println(HasRuntime.uType()) // Universe (not RuntimeUniverse)
}
```

Even simpler example:

```
trait MyTypeclass[A] {
  def apply(): String
}
object MyTypeclass {
  implicit def parent[A <: Parent]: MyTypeclass[A] = () => "Parent"
  implicit val child: MyTypeclass[Child.type] = () => "Child"
}

trait Parent {
  type T <: Parent
  def uType: MyTypeclass[T] = implicitly
}

object Child extends Parent {
  override type T = Child.type
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  println(Child.uType()) // Parent (not Child)
}
```

If you want implicits to resolve in the line `println(Child.uType)` then add an implicit parameter to the method

```
trait MyTypeclass[A] {
  def apply(): String
}
object MyTypeclass {
  implicit def parent[A <: Parent]: MyTypeclass[A] = () => "Parent"
  implicit val child: MyTypeclass[Child.type] = () => "Child"
}

trait Parent {
  type T <: Parent
  def uType(implicit mtc: MyTypeclass[T]): MyTypeclass[T] = implicitly
     // the same as
  // def uType(implicit mtc: MyTypeclass[T]): MyTypeclass[T] = mtc
}

object Child extends Parent {
  override type T = Child.type
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  println(Child.uType.apply()) // Child
}
```

```
trait MyTypeclass[A] {
  def apply(): String
}
object MyTypeclass {
  implicit def universe[U <: Universe]: MyTypeclass[U] = () => "Universe"
  implicit val runtimeUniverse: MyTypeclass[RuntimeUniverse.type] = () => "RuntimeUniverse"
}

trait Universe
object RuntimeUniverse extends Universe

trait HasUniverse {
  val universe: Universe with Singleton

  def uType(implicit mtc: MyTypeclass[universe.type]): MyTypeclass[universe.type] = implicitly
     // the same as
  // def uType(implicit mtc: MyTypeclass[universe.type]): MyTypeclass[universe.type] = mtc
}

object HasRuntime extends HasUniverse {
  override val universe: RuntimeUniverse.type = RuntimeUniverse
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  println(HasRuntime.uType.apply()) // RuntimeUniverse
}
```

```
import scala.reflect.api.Universe

val RuntimeUniverse = scala.reflect.runtime.universe

trait HasUniverse {
  val universe: Universe with Singleton

  def uType(implicit ttag: RuntimeUniverse.TypeTag[universe.type]): RuntimeUniverse.TypeTag[universe.type] = implicitly
     // the same as
  // def uType(implicit ttag: RuntimeUniverse.TypeTag[universe.type]): RuntimeUniverse.TypeTag[universe.type] = ttag
}

object HasRuntime extends HasUniverse {
  override val universe: RuntimeUniverse.type = RuntimeUniverse
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  println(HasRuntime.uType) // TypeTag[HasRuntime.universe.type]
}
```

One more option to postpone implicit resolution besides adding an implicit parameter is inlining (with `inline` in Scala 3 or a macro in Scala 2)

[Why the Scala compiler can provide implicit outside of object, but cannot inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74437826/why-the-scala-compiler-can-provide-implicit-outside-of-object-but-cannot-inside) ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74439731/5249621))

[Type parameter for implicit valued method in Scala - Circe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74364545/type-parameter-for-implicit-valued-method-in-scala-circe/)

[Implicit Json Formatter for value classes in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71425914/implicit-json-formatter-for-value-classes-in-scala)

> due to `implicitly` only able to see `universe.type`, which is not known at call site. (in contrast, `WeakTypeTag[universe.type]` should totally work)

Here you seem to have one more confusion. The **type** `universe.type` is not abstract, it's a singleton type inhabited by the `val universe` of `trait HasUniverse`. It's `val universe` that is abstract but not its type.

> Abstract value types are introduced by type parameters and abstract type bindings.

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html

Comment: Thanks a lot professor, I think my biggest concern here is that an incomplete `TypeTag` shouldn't be allowed to be created, considering that its intention was to replace `ClassTag`

Comment: @tribbloid `HasUniverse.this.universe.type` is not "incomplete", it's absolutely legitimate non-abstract singleton type. I've never heard about intentions to replace `ClassTag` with `TypeTag`. `ClassTag`, `TypeTag`, `WeakTypeTag` are not better or worse than each other, they are just needed in different situations. Sometimes you need to know erased information about a type, sometimes you need to know complete information about a type. Sometimes it's important that type is not abstract, sometimes it's ok if a type is abstract.

Comment: @tribbloid According to Scaladocs, 1) "*A `ClassTag[T]` stores the erased class of a given type `T`, accessible via the `runtimeClass` field. This is particularly useful for instantiating Arrays whose element types are unknown at compile time.
`ClassTag`s are a weaker special case of `TypeTag`s, in that they wrap only the runtime class of a given type, whereas a `TypeTag` contains all static type information. That is, `ClassTag`s are constructed from knowing only the top-level class of a type, without necessarily knowing all of its argument types.*

Comment: @tribbloid *This runtime information is enough for runtime Array creation.*" 2) "*A `TypeTag` is a `WeakTypeTag` with the additional static guarantee that all type references are concrete, i.e. it does not contain any references to unresolved type parameters or abstract types.*"

Comment: @tribbloid In Scala singleton types are not only `ConstantType`s inhabited by literals like types `1` or `"a"` but also `SingleType`s inhabited by terms like `someValue.type` or `SomeObject.type` (there are also `ThisType` `this.type` and `SuperType` `super.type`). The type `HasUniverse.this.universe.type` is inhabited by `HasUniverse.this.universe`.