# exception during macro expansion: type T is not a class, play json

Tags: scala, scala-macros, play-json

I'm facing this error:

```
exception during macro expansion: 
scala.ScalaReflectionException: type T is not a class
    at scala.reflect.api.Symbols$SymbolApi.asClass(Symbols.scala:284)
    at scala.reflect.api.Symbols$SymbolApi.asClass$(Symbols.scala:284)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$SymbolContextApiImpl.asClass(Symbols.scala:99)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsMacroImpl.directKnownSubclasses$1(JsMacroImpl.scala:527)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsMacroImpl.macroImpl(JsMacroImpl.scala:850)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsMacroImpl.implicitConfigWritesImpl(JsMacroImpl.scala:44)
```

When trying to declare a method to create the writer for a given generic type:

```scala
def makeWriter[T]: Writes[T] = Json.writes[T]
```

Now the implementation of the `Json.writes` is just a macro, and it doesn't require any sort of context bounds or something:

```scala
def writes[A]: OWrites[A] = macro JsMacroImpl.withOptionsWritesImpl[A]
```

Does anyone know what's going on here? I'm not really good at macros, so I'd appreciate if anyone could explain this, any solution is appreciated.

Comment: yeah, you can't do that. Type parameter to a macro needs to be concrete. `Json.writes[Foo]` works, `Json.writes[T]` does not. The reason is that macro is expanded at compile time, so, the type needs to be fully known.

Comment: As the compile error say the macro is inspecting the type `T`, checking if it belongs to a `class` _(probably even a `case class`)_. And then, it will generate the code to produce the `Writes` instance for the given type. That makes sense when the type is concrete, for an abstract type it simply can't do that. That is why if you want to use this in an abstract method, rather you need to ask for the `Writes` instance of `T` instead of wanting to derive it there.

Comment: You didn't give info about your context but one "solution" could be to NOT use `makeWriter[T]` bur rather ask for `T` to have a `Writes` in scope via implicit/given or [context bound](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/ca-context-bounds.html) `T : Writes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

The stack trace

```
scala.ScalaReflectionException: type T is not a class
    at scala.reflect.api.Symbols$SymbolApi.asClass(Symbols.scala:284)
    at scala.reflect.api.Symbols$SymbolApi.asClass$(Symbols.scala:284)
    at scala.reflect.internal.Symbols$SymbolContextApiImpl.asClass(Symbols.scala:99)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsMacroImpl.directKnownSubclasses$1(JsMacroImpl.scala:555)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsMacroImpl.macroImpl(JsMacroImpl.scala:869)
    at play.api.libs.json.JsMacroImpl.implicitConfigWritesImpl(JsMacroImpl.scala:44)
```

gives a hint what the problems is:

```scala
    def directKnownSubclasses: Option[List[Type]] = {
      // Workaround for SI-7046: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-7046
      val tpeSym = atag.tpe.typeSymbol.asClass  //  <------
      ...
```

https://github.com/playframework/play-json/blob/main/play-json/shared/src/main/scala-2/play/api/libs/json/JsMacroImpl.scala#L555

`.asClass` can be called only on class symbols, otherwise it throws (and runtime exceptions of macros are compile errors of main code)

```scala
def asClass: ClassSymbol = throw new ScalaReflectionException(s"$this is not a class")
```

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/api/Symbols.scala#L284

The problem of the definition

```scala
def makeWriter[T]: Writes[T] = Json.writes[T]
```

is that the macro `Json.writes[T]` is expanded here where `T` is not a class yet but just a type parameter. **You can postpone macro expansion** if you make your `makeWriter` a macro as well

```scala
import play.api.libs.json.Writes
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def makeWriter[T]: Writes[T] = macro makeWriterImpl[T]

def makeWriterImpl[T: c.WeakTypeTag](c: blackbox.Context): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val typeT = weakTypeOf[T]
  q"_root_.play.api.libs.json.Json.writes[$typeT]"
}
```

```scala
// in a different subproject

case class A(i: Int)

makeWriter[A] // compiles
```

[Implicit Json Formatter for value classes in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71425914/implicit-json-formatter-for-value-classes-in-scala)

[In scala 2, can macro or any language feature be used to rewrite the abstract type reification mechanism in all subclasses? How about scala 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67258252/in-scala-2-can-macro-or-any-language-feature-be-used-to-rewrite-the-abstract-ty)

[Why the Scala compiler can provide implicit outside of object, but cannot inside?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74437826/why-the-scala-compiler-can-provide-implicit-outside-of-object-but-cannot-inside) ([answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74439731/5249621))

[Type parameter for implicit valued method in Scala - Circe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74364545/type-parameter-for-implicit-valued-method-in-scala-circe)

[Parametric polymorphism issue with spark implicits, value toDF is not a member of Seq[T]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75915719/parametric-polymorphism-issue-with-spark-implicits-value-todf-is-not-a-member-o)

**Another solution** to postpone macro expansion is to postpone implicit resolution (this postpones macro expansion because macros are now used to define implicits, i.e. instances of the type class `Writes`)

```scala
def makeWriter[T: Writes]: Writes[T] = implicitly[Writes[T]]
// aka
//def makeWriter[T](implicit writes: Writes[T]): Writes[T] = writes
```

See about the difference between `implicitly[X]` and `(implicit x: X)`

[When doing implicit resolution with type parameters, why does val placement matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59391232/when-doing-implicit-resolution-with-type-parameters-why-does-val-placement-matt)

[Setting abstract type based on typeclass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64238219/setting-abstract-type-based-on-typeclass)

> and it doesn't require any sort of context bounds or something:

You have correct suspection that context bounds (implicit parameters) can be hidden via macros (although now the reason of error was different):

```scala
def foo()(implicit a: A) = ()
```

can become

```scala
def foo(): Unit = macro fooImpl

def fooImpl(c: blackbox.Context)(): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  c.inferImplicitValue(typeOf[A], silent = false)
  q"()"
}
```

(so `def foo(): Unit` now pretends that it doesn't require implicit `A` although actually it does).