# SYB `cast` function in Scala

Tags: scala, implicit, shapeless, scrap-your-boilerplate, syb

I am reading the [Scrap Your Boilerplate](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2003/01/hmap.pdf) paper and trying to follow along by implementing the ideas in scala as best I can. However, I'm stuck on the very first function, the `cast`, which is used to take a value and attempt to cast it to another type in an `Option`, obviously a `Some` if the cast is successful, and `None` otherwise. I have a version of it working with the following code:

```scala
  trait Cast[A, B]:
    def apply(a: A): Option[B]

  object Cast:
    given cSome[A, B](using t: A =:= B): Cast[A, B] with
      def apply(a: A) = Some(t(a))

    given cNone[A, B](using t: NotGiven[A =:= B]): Cast[A, B] with
      def apply(a: A) = None
```

This works when types are statically known. Trying the examples from the paper:

```scala
  val maybeChar = summon[Cast[Char, Char]]('a')  // Some(a)
  val maybeBool = summon[Cast[Char, Boolean]]('a')  // None
  val maybeBool2 = summon[Cast[Boolean, Boolean]](true) // Some(true)
```

However, when I try to clean up the ergonomics a bit so that we can rely on type inference as in the examples in the paper with a generic helper defined as such:

```scala
  def cast[A, B](a: A): Option[B] = summon[Cast[A, B]](a)
```

I'm getting only `None`s, meaning the types are never being seen as the same:

```scala
  val mc: Option[Char] = cast('a')  // None
  val mb: Option[Boolean] = cast('a')  // None 
  val mb2: Option[Boolean] = cast(true)  // None
```

The same happens even when I'm being explicit with the types:

```scala
  val mc: Option[Char] = cast[Char, Char]('a')  // None
  val mb: Option[Boolean] = cast[Char, Boolean]('a')  // None
  val mb2: Option[Boolean] = cast[Boolean, Boolean](true)  // None
```

I'm using scala 3.2. Is there any way to achieve this cast function with the less verbose ergonomics? I'm even more curious why what I have isn't working, especially with the explicit casting? I'm pretty sure `shapeless` is able to provide an SYB implementation in scala 2, albeit probably relying on macros. Can we do this in scala 3 without macros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed an implicit parameter

```
def cast[A, B](a: A)(using Cast[A, B]): Option[B] = summon[Cast[A, B]](a)
//                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

[When doing implicit resolution with type parameters, why does val placement matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59391232/when-doing-implicit-resolution-with-type-parameters-why-does-val-placement-matt) (`implicitly[X]` vs. `(implicit x: X)` in Scala 2, `summon[X]` vs. `(using X)` in Scala 3)

Comment: Yep, that was it, thank you! I'm curious now, what was happening at compile time without that? Why was it that `cNone` was the instance being `summon`ed?

Comment: @anqit Please see the link about the difference `implicitly[X]` vs. `(implicit x: X)` in Scala 2 (or `summon[X]` vs. `(using X)` in Scala 3).

Comment: Thanks for the link, that makes sense, the difference between declaration vs use-site implicit resolution. At the declaration, there's nothing saying `A =:= B`